# What is the difference between ~/ and ~ in Linux?

Tags: linux, redhat

I am novice to Linux, using it a little more than a year. Can anybody help me resolve my question?

When I use `~/` only it shows user home directory. Why does it not work in the case of using `~` alone to specify path to a file or directory?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`~` means the home directory of the logged on user whereas `~/` means the path to the beginning of a directory.

From [here](http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Wikilearn/TildeSlash):

> The tilde (~) is a Linux "shortcut" to denote a user's home directory.
>   Thus tilde slash (~/) is the beginning of a path to a file or
>   directory below the user's home directory.

**On a side note**  If you see like `~Gowthaman/`  then it will be the user Gowthaman home directory

Comment: root dir of application??

Comment: @vish4071:- Added some more details with a reference. Hope that helps!

Comment: Still I think that "root dir of _application_" is very strange or even missleading. Actually, the source you quote gives a much better explanation ("... is the beginning of a path to a file below the user's home directory..."). IOW "~/" has no special meaning. Just like "./" has no special meaning (appart from the ".").

Comment: @Christian.K:- Agreed. Updated the misleading part

Comment: I am very much confusing in what is user's home directory whether it refer /home or /home/<foo user>/